# App Engine PHP include not found

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When include a PHP file

```
> Warning: require_once(...): failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in /base/data/home/apps/...
```

PHP says this error but file exists.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check for file permissions?

Comment: Please show us a image of your directory, and your include path.

Comment: PHP doesn't include files except files in same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say I have the path .../htdocs/folder1/hello.php
So I am now on the hello.php file and I want to include the bye_bye.php ... 
If it's in the same folder you can use.

`require_once __DIR__ ."/bye_bye.php";`

I don't know your whole path so I'm sorry if that doesn't helped you.